# Stuck in a recursive loop

Tags: java, string, recursion

I am working on a class assignment where I have to use recursive code to take different words out of a list and formulate sentences. For the most part, that part of my code works but the problem is, It wont stop. I will post my code below and any pointers or solution will be much appreciated.

```
/*
 * A program that implements BNF rules to generate random sentences.
 * 
 * The program generates and outputs one random sentence every three
 * seconds until it is halted (for example, by typing Control-C in the
 * terminal window where it is running).
 * 
 * The rules that this program follows are:
 * 
 * <sentence> ::= <simple_sentence> [ <conjunction> <sentence> ]
 * 
 * <simple_sentence> ::= this is a <adjective> project <conjunction> 
 * <noun_phrase> <verb_phrase>
 * 
 * <noun_phrase> ::= <proper_noun> | 
 * <determiner> [ <adjective> ]. <common_noun> [ who <verb_phrase> ]
 * 
 * <verb_phrase> ::= <intransitive_verb> | 
 * <transitive_verb> <noun_phrase> |
 * is <adjective> |
 * believes that <simple_sentence>
 * 
 * Rules for nouns, verbs, conjunctions, etc. are implemented by arrays.
 */
package randomrecursion;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author Xavier
 */

    public class RandomRecursion {

    // Implement arrays for last seven rules in the list.
    private static final String[] conjunctions = { "and", "or", "but", 
        "because", "since", "when" };

    private static final String[] properNouns = { "Fred", "Jane", 
        "Richard Nixon", "Miss America", "Berry White", "Jeff Dunham" };

    private static final String[] commonNouns = { "man", "woman", "fish",
        "elephant", "ball", "planet", "model", "stunt-man" };

    private static final String[] determiners = { "a", "the", "every", "some",
        "each", "neither", "either" };

    private static final String[] adjectives = { "big", "tiny", "pretty",
        "bald", "odd", "scary", "unfortunate", "nice", "rediculus", "carefree" };

    private static final String[] intransitiveVerbs = { "runs", "jumps",
        "talks", "sleeps", "eats", "cries", "laughs" };

    private static final String[] transitiveVerbs = { "loves", "hates", "sees",
        "knows", "lives", "hunts", "accepts", "cleans" };

    // Instantiate a Random() object.
    private static final Random rGen = new Random();

    /* 
     * rGen will be used by chanceToBeTrue to select a double in the
     * range 0-1.  If the value is less than SMALL_CHANCE,
     * chanceToBeTrue(SMALL_CHANCE) returns true.
     * MEDIUM_CHANCE and LARGE_CHANCE work in the same way.
     * 0.1 is equivalent to a 10% chance.
     */
    private static final double SMALL_CHANCE = 0.1;
    private static final double MEDIUM_CHANCE = 0.5;
    private static final double LARGE_CHANCE = 0.75;

    /*
     * Values will be added together and used with if/else statements
     * to determine probabilities for branches in the verbPhrase()
     * routine.  0.1 is equivalent to a 10% chance.
     */
    private static final double CHANCE_FOR_INTRANSITIVE = 0.4;
    private static final double CHANCE_FOR_TRANSITIVE = 0.1;
    private static final double CHANCE_FOR_ADJECTIVE = 0.4;

    private static final int MILLISECONDS_TO_SLEEP = 2000;

    /**
     * This routine calls the randomSentence routine to generate random 
     * sentences in a loop, pausing for MILLISECONDS_TO_SLEEP in
     * between each sentence.
     * 
     * @param args Command line args (not used).
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while (true) {
            randomSentence();
            System.out.println(".\n\n");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(MILLISECONDS_TO_SLEEP);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This routine creates one random sentence following this rule:
     * 
     * <sentence> ::= <simple_sentence> [ <conjunction> <sentence> ]
     */
    private static void randomSentence() {

        simpleSentence();

        if (chanceToBeTrue(SMALL_CHANCE)) {
            randomItem(conjunctions);
            System.out.print(" ");
            randomSentence();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This routine creates a simple sentence following this rule:
     * 
     * <simple_sentence> ::= this is a <adjective> project <conjunction>
     * <noun_phrase> <verb_phrase>
     */
    private static void simpleSentence() {

        makeItInteresting();
        nounPhrase();
        verbPhrase();
    }

    /**
     * This routine adds an interesting beginning to each simpleSentence.
     */
    private static void makeItInteresting() {
        System.out.print("this is a");
        randomItem(adjectives);
        System.out.print(" project");
        randomItem(conjunctions);
    }

    /**
     * This routine creates a noun phrase following this rule:
     * 
     * <noun_phrase> ::= <proper_noun> |
     * <determiner> [ <adjective> ] <common_noun> [ who <verb_phrase> ]
     */
    private static void nounPhrase() {

        if (chanceToBeTrue(MEDIUM_CHANCE)) {
            randomItem(properNouns);
        } else {
            randomItem(determiners);
            if (chanceToBeTrue(LARGE_CHANCE)) {
                randomItem(adjectives);
            }
            randomItem(commonNouns);
            if (chanceToBeTrue(SMALL_CHANCE)) {
                System.out.print(" who");
                verbPhrase();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This routine creates a verb phrase following this rule:
     * 
     * <verb_phrase> ::= <intransitive_verb> |
     * <transitive_verb> <noun_phrase> |
     * is <adjective> |
     * believes that <simple_sentence>
     */
    private static void verbPhrase() {

        // Instantiate a random double between 0.0 (inclusive)
        // and 0.1 (exclusive).
        double chance = rGen.nextDouble();

        if (chance < CHANCE_FOR_INTRANSITIVE) {
            randomItem(intransitiveVerbs);
        } else if (chance < (CHANCE_FOR_INTRANSITIVE + CHANCE_FOR_TRANSITIVE)) {
            randomItem(transitiveVerbs);
            nounPhrase();
        } else if (chance < (CHANCE_FOR_INTRANSITIVE
                             + CHANCE_FOR_TRANSITIVE + CHANCE_FOR_ADJECTIVE)) {
            System.out.print(" is");
            randomItem(adjectives);
        } else {
            System.out.print(" believes that ");
            simpleSentence();
        }
    }    

    /**
     * This routine randomly chooses an item from an array of strings.    
     */
    private static void randomItem(String[] listOfStrings) {

        /* 
         * Get next integer from rGen that is between 0 (inclusive) and 
         * listOfStrings.length (exclusive) and print that randomly chosen
         * element of the list of Strings.
         */
        int choice = rGen.nextInt(listOfStrings.length);
        System.out.print(" " + listOfStrings[choice]);
    }


    /**
     * This routine uses rGen to return true percentChance amount
     * of the time.
     * 
     * @param percentChance double value between 0.0 (inclusive)
     *     and 1.0 (exclusive).
     * @return true if a randomly chosen double value
     *     is less than percentChance.
     */
    private static boolean chanceToBeTrue(double percentChance) {

        double number = rGen.nextDouble();
        if (number < percentChance) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it won't stop? The requirement is for it to print one every three seconds, and therefore not to stop.

Comment: When or in which case do you want it to stop/return from the loop? according to that you can set the case check in the while loop instead of writing true.

Comment: The only "problem" I see is that you have put a SMALL_CHANCE in the randomSentence(), so it will stop aproximately a near every ten sentences. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't stopping because of the infinite `while-loop` in your `main`

```
while (true) {
    randomSentence();
    System.out.println(".\n\n");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(MILLISECONDS_TO_SLEEP);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }
}
```

Not because of recursion.